# How to define types for generic react Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I struggle to figure out how to type things properly.
I have a generic `IPost` type declared as:

```
export enum PostKind {
  Message = "message",
  Food = "food",
}

export type IPost<T extends PostKind> = {
  type: T;
  content: PostContent<T>; // not including the code for this type since is not relevant for now.
};
```

I have specific post types that extend this type:

```
export type IMessagePost = IPost<PostKind.Message> & {
  messageLength: number;
};

export type IFoodPost = IPost<PostKind.Message> & {
  image: string;
};
```

I have components for each specific post type:

```
export const MessagePost = (props: IMessagePost) => {
  return <div>{props.messageLength}</div>;
};

export const FoodPost = (props: IFoodPost) => {
  return <div>{props.image}</div>;
};
```

All good so far. New I want a generic `Post` component that takes an `IPost` param and displays the correct component that matches the `PostKind`.

```
const componentMap: Record<
  PostKind,
  React.FC<IMessagePost> | React.FC<IFoodPost>
> = {
  [PostKind.Message]: MessagePost,
  [PostKind.Food]: FoodPost,
};

export const Post = (props: IPost<PostKind>) => {
  const Component = componentMap[props.type];
  return <Component {...props} />; // typescript error here: Type 'PostKind' is not assignable to type 'PostKind.Message'
};
```

Something is worng with my types, and I cannot find a proper solution. Typescript shows the following error:

```
Type '{ type: PostKind; }' is not assignable to type 'IPost<PostKind.Message>'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'PostKind' is not assignable to type 'PostKind.Message'.
```

You can check the full code, and see the error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljiQDsBXPABQgGcYBpYRgCZwA3uThwAskk6cUAcyRwAvARDTZC-ABoxcAGIQIQlfkyGB28gF9KNOvBgBPMIoCSHbgB4AKg2owmAU44D15%20AQA%20ZRFdJxcALjhvCisKKlpoB2c3KRl5JFDo9y4YT1C%20QQA6XI0kKIAyGPE1PIUAGSY5GAALRJYQACMkKBS0u0y4OLcDI0KVYq9y8Or1fIamuFB8xO4ofjlR2wz6NAhGbklVhTm4AAowHDBORNca-NCASmUo0XEiGGYUEYcE8AmAADcIsIHhAnpUWrUOowut0rJ4APRgyGHdL2OCnc7wGYCG73R7POCuYmfb4bf6A4GgiFQmFwrYKNGY5k4gkXU7gM5MGASFBgRLIU5QASeXRLQQ6cTIdAwSp6ADCnleVwKJSiAB9EMQVerNdTdeQoipfnAANpygQrVpIAC6iTe1xKCtt9tV5ld%20nMoR0qSOeN58FJrIpC1K9oiXyUP104bgatwkEYQui-IzQpFYBtUcqU2dFD%20SABQJBaYFmcY8GElSbUascHREUOQA):

Please don't suggest solution that uses types like `unknown` `any` `ElementType` `ReactNode`, or using the `as` keyword. I want everything to be typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think in order for it to be sensible, the definition should be like this, right?

```
export type IFoodPost = IPost<PostKind.Food> & {
  image: string;
};
```

Then, you can replace the last part with this:

```
const componentMap = {
  [PostKind.Message]: MessagePost,
  [PostKind.Food]: FoodPost,
};

export const Post1 = <A extends IPost<B>, B extends PostKind & keyof C, C extends Record<B, (a: A) => JSX.Element>>(props: A, rec: C) => {
   const Component = rec[props.type]
   return React.createElement(Component, props)
};

export const Post = <A extends IPost<PostKind>>(props: A) => {
    return Post1(props, componentMap)
};
```

Given that, the `<Post />` component will work if you type it explicitely:

```
const c1 = <Post<IMessagePost> type={PostKind.Message} messageLength={88} />
const c2 = <Post<IFoodPost> type={PostKind.Food} image={"xxxx"} />
const c3 = <Post<IFoodPost> type={PostKind.Food} /> // fails to typecheck
const c4 = <Post<IFoodPost> type={PostKind.Food} messageLength={5} /> // fails to typecheck
```